# Access static resources Spring MVC 4

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have set the Spring MVC as below but the logo.png image is not shown. I'm using Spring 4.2.0.RELEASE

Image logo.png is under src/main/resources/images/logo.png

AppWebConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="br.com.casadocodigo.loja")
public class AppWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean(name="messageSource")
public MessageSource messageResource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bundle = 
            new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    bundle.setBasename("WEB-INF/messages");
    bundle.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    bundle.setCacheSeconds(1);
    return bundle;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/images")
        .setCachePeriod(3600)
        .resourceChain(true)
        .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());   
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

}
```

ServletSpringMVC.java

```
public class ServletSpringMVC extends 
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] {AppWebConfiguration.class, JPAConfiguration.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] {"/"};
}

}
```

JSP Page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<div>
    <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/logo.png" 
alt=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: `/src/main/resources` is the root of the class path your current configuration looks at `/src/main/resources/resources/images`. You are also configuring a resource chain but have a `PathResolver` so configured that it will always return `null`.

Comment: How do you suggest setting this up? @M.Deinum

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
}
```